# Why am I getting “Error 25: Expected: ;” in this function definition?

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I am debugging a function for a Photoshop script:

```
function artboardRename (artboard, param1, param2, param3) {
    let vis = artboard.visible;
    alert(vis);
}
// artboard is a layerSet
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
Error 25: Expected: ;. Line 202 -> let vis = artboard.visible;
```

Why do I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 5):

There's no `let` in photoshop scripting because Adobe ExtendScript is based currently on EcmaScript version 3. This also means there's no very basic features such as Array.indexOf(), nevermind the ES5 and 6 syntaxes.

The correct code that should work is:

```
function artboardRename (artboard, param1, param2, param3) {
var vis = artboard.visible;
alert(vis);
```

}